# django-cms refusing to publish a specific page in production - where should I start debugging?

Tags: django, apache, logging, django-cms

I have a small problem in my production cms. One of the pages (There are about 50) is refusing to be published. I mean: if I click on "publish" in the admin interface or use the method publish_page I am not getting any errors. On the page list view there's a green check by this page. But when I browse in there, I am getting a nice 404 error. And if I refresh the page list view, the green check turns into a red sign (not published).

I don't know where should I start debugging this issue.

```
>>> from cms.api import publish_page
>>> p = Page.objects.get(pk__exact=66)
>>> r = User.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> p2 = publish_page(p, r)
>>> p2
<cms.models.pagemodel.Page object at 0x3561910>
>>> p2.is_public_published()
True
```

There are no error traces in my /var/log/httpd/access_log nor /var/log/httpd/error_log (apart of the 404 warning). These are my logging settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'department.models': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest me where to start debugging? Thanks!

Roberto

UPDATE:

My virtual environment has the following installed:

```
Django          - 1.5.4        - active 
PIL             - 1.1.7        - active 
Pillow          - 2.2.1        - active 
Pygments        - 1.6          - active 
Python          - 2.7.3        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
South           - 0.8.2        - active 
argparse        - 1.2.1        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7)
bpython         - 0.12         - active 
cmsplugin-news  - 0.4.2        - active 
django-autoslug - 1.7.1        - active 
django-ckeditor - 4.0.2        - active 
django-classy-tags - 0.4          - active 
django-cms      - 2.4.2        - active 
django-country-dialcode - 0.4.8        - active 
django-extensions - 1.2.2        - active 
django-guardian - 1.1.1        - active 
django-hvad     - 0.3          - active 
django-modeltranslation - 0.6.1        - active 
django-mptt     - 0.5.2        - active 
django-reusableapps - 0.1.1        - active 
django-reversion - 1.7.1        - active 
django-sekizai  - 0.7          - active 
djangocms-text-ckeditor - 1.0.10       - active 
html5lib        - 1.0b3        - active 
pip             - 1.2.1        - active 
psycopg2        - 2.5.1        - active 
python-ldap     - 2.4.13       - active 
python-magic    - 0.4.6        - active 
pytz            - 2013.7       - active 
setuptools      - 1.1.6        - active 
six             - 1.4.1        - active 
switch2bill-common - 2.8.1        - active 
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7)
```

Comment: Please provide the django, cms and python versions used

Comment: I ran into similar problem once with django-cms. If i remember correctly it had something to do with the cms specific settings related to who could publish pages and if pages had to get admin review.

Answer (score 1):

The list-view of pages is Django-CMS is largely powered by ajax requests.

I would take a look at that view using Firebug to see if any of the publishing functions are returning 500 errors from ajax requests that won't cause the view itself to throw a 500.

I've had plugins get corrupted which in turn caused publishing to fail. In the list-view of pages, the pages appear to publish correctly, as checkboxes get checked, etc, but in Firebug those ajax POST requests were returning 500 errors.